# Solving modular equation

Tags: divisibility

$$13863x \equiv 12282 \pmod {32394}$$

I need to solve this equation. If I'd found the inverse of 13863 and multiply the equation by this, I'd get the solution. So:

$$13863c \equiv 1 \pmod {32394}$$

And now - how can I find this inverse? The numbers are too big to just look for the multiplier of $13863$ . . .

Comment: As $(13863,32394)$ divides $3,$ you won't get the inverse

Comment: @lab Probably you mean the reverse, i.e. $\ 3\mid 13863,32394\,\Rightarrow\, 3\mid 13863c - 32394d = 1\,\Rightarrow\Leftarrow\quad$

Comment: @user78535, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\gcd$ if $32394$ and $13863$ is $3$, so there is no inverse. What you need to do is divide out any common factors in the original equation: everything here is divisible by $3$.
$$13863x\equiv 12282\bmod 32394$$
In general, if you want to solve $$dx\equiv da\bmod dm,$$
then for any solution $y$ of the congruence $x\equiv a\bmod m$, the numbers $$y,\quad y+m,\quad\ldots,\quad y+(d-1)m$$
will all be solutions to $dx\equiv da\bmod dm$, because
$$d(y+km)=dy+k(dm)\equiv dy\equiv da\bmod dm.$$
When faced with a congruence where the $\gcd$ of all the terms, *together* with the modulus, is not $1$, divide through by their $\gcd$, solve that congruence, and then "move back up" to obtain the solutions to your original congruence.

---

So, let's solve
$$4621x\equiv 4094\bmod 10798$$
(which is what we get after dividing everything by their $\gcd$ of $3$). As you've noted in your question, we want to find the inverse for $4621$ modulo $10798$.

Run the Euclidean algorithm for computing $\gcd(4621,10798)$:
$$\begin{align*}
10798 &= 2\cdot 4621 + 1556\\
4621&= 2\cdot 1556 + 1509\\
4668&=1\cdot 1509 + 47\\
1509 & = 32\cdot 47+ 5\\
47&= 9\cdot 5+2\\
5&=2\cdot 2+\fbox{1}\\
2&=2\cdot 1+0
\end{align*}$$
then "run it backwards":
$$\begin{align*}
\fbox{1}&=\mathbf{5-2\cdot2}\\
&\quad =5-2\cdot (47-9\cdot 5)\\
&\quad =5-2\cdot 47+ 18\cdot 5\\\\
&=-2\cdot 47+ 19\cdot 5\\
&\quad=-2\cdot 47+19\cdot(1509- 32\cdot 47)\\
&\quad= -2\cdot 47+19\cdot 1509-608\cdot 47)\\\\
&=19\cdot 1509-610\cdot 47\\
&\\
&\vdots\\
&\\
&=u\cdot 4621+v\cdot 10798
\end{align*}$$
And now we have our inverse: $u$, because
$$u\cdot 4621=1-v\cdot 10798$$
implies that
$$u\cdot 4621\equiv 1\bmod 10798.$$

Comment: Oh, now I feel terrible for not actually checking that they were relatively prime.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\ {\rm mod}\,\ 3m\!:\ 3ax\equiv 3b\iff 3m\mid 3ax-3b \iff  m\mid ax-b\iff {\rm mod}\,\ m\!:\ ax\equiv b $